# How to find out the number of a C++ warning

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have turned on `-Wall` in my code to get rid of all warnings. Some however I want to allow within the code, so I disable those ones in code. Of the common ones, I can easily find out the warning number in Google and disable them like e.g.:

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4127 )
```

But of some, I can't possibly find the corresponding number. For example, I want to disable a:

`warning : array subscript is of type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]`

How do I find its number? Is there a searchable list?  The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/) isn't searchable on keyword, only on number.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-by-compiler-version But your warning and switches do not look like form a Microsoft compiler?! They have a slash like `/Wall`. And the warnings include the number. These look like gcc/clang warnings.

Comment: The MS compiler tells you the warning number.`warning : array subscript is of type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]` is not an output of the MS compiler.

Comment: The MS warnings are like this:  _warning __C4700__: uninitialized local variable 'x' used_

Comment: You can disable such warning with: `-Wno-char-subscripts` as a compiler option. And generally replace `-W` with `-Wno-` to disable a specific warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: array subscript has type char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972359/warning-array-subscript-has-type-char)

Comment: "I have turned on -Wall in my code to get rid of all warnings. " ??   In g++ or clang++ "-Wall" does not disable any warnings, but instead turns on a few (not anywhere near 'all').   More importantly, 'Warnings' are a good thing to enable!  To eliminate warnings, you need to a) write correct code, and b) fix your warning generating code.  My typical compile has >45 warning-checks enabled, and none explicitly disabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using a Microsoft compiler, or at least not a Microsoft compiler front end.  The warning is printed by the Clang front end.  (GCC has a very similar warning, also called `-Wchar-subscripts`, but the wording of the message is slightly different.)

Clang and GCC do not use numbers for warnings, but names.  You can use these pragmata to disable the diagnostic:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wchar-subscripts"
```

The code which should be compiled without the warning follows, and with this, you can restore the previous state of the warning (typically enabled):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Note that it says “`GCC`” because the pragma actually works with GCC and Clang.